# How can i run "node index.js" in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

This has been created in windows environment how can run it into a ubuntu environment.

```
stayinc/server$ node index.js 

util.js:538
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:538:43)
    at Object. (/media/subhasis/3C92D33592D2F27E/LocalProject/stayinc/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs-stream/download.js:46:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object. (/media/subhasis/3C92D33592D2F27E/LocalProject/stayinc/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs-stream/index.js:2:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

Comment: Can you show the code in the index.js file? It is hard to debug with so little information.

Comment: What is `superCtor` supposed to be?  It is apparently `undefined` here when you need to   have a real value.  We need to see a lot more of the relevant code to have any idea what is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the following command before running "node index.js"?

```
npm install
```

Comment: Also maybe the OP forgot to correctly setup his/her `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

It must be an issue with an outdated version of `node.js`.

You could check the current version by typing in

```
node -v
```

I suppose it would output something like `0.8`, which is pretty old.